# How can i use the apostrophe-oembed to embed data using an iframe?

Tags: javascript, apostrophe-cms

How can i use the apostrophe-oembed to embed data from another website using an iframe? I have gone through the documentations but were of little help.

Answer (score 0):

[`apostrophe-video-fields`](https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe/blob/91315a6247296ffbb88730c1f0453bc2354a0e89/lib/modules/apostrophe-video-fields/public/js/user.js#L62-L77) is probably the best example of how `apostrophe-oembed` is used. There is some complexity there, but I'd need to see where you are in your code before saying what you might need to change.

Keep in mind that this only works for [endpoints that Oembed supports](https://oembed.com/#section7). If you're trying to display some random website in an iframe, you should be looking at `apostrophe-html` and adding an iframe in there. Or, even better, create a custom widget that has a `url` field, makes sure it's safe, then puts it in an iframe in the widget template (or a custom piece/page schema field as appropriate).